# Formtastic/ActiveAdmin set a default value for a select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I am working on a custom form in ActiveAdmin which I decided to use it for adding/editing to follow the `DRY` principle so I need to populate it if the user uses it for editing a record ( which isn't a DB record ).

So the problem is I have those inputs :

```
f.input :model_id, as: :select, collection: Model.all.map { |m| [m.id.to_s + ' - ' + m.name, m.id] }, input_html: { required: true }
f.input :enabled, as: :select, collection: {'Yes': true, 'No': false}, input_html: { required: true }
```

And I'd like to set a default value for them if I'm using the form for editing but I failed to know how because everybody is talking about using `belongs_to` or a DB relation and `ActiveAdmin` will take care of the default value for you which isn't applicable for my case because it's not a DB record and I don't have an `ActiveRecord Model` for it.

Even the [official docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput) of `Formtastic` didn't help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out how to do it and here is the answer for anyone facing the same problem :

```
f.input :model_id, collection: Model.all.map { |m| [m.id.to_s + ' - ' + m.name, m.id] }, selected: object.model_id
f.input :enabled, collection: { 'Yes': true, 'No': false }, selected: object.enabled
```

Comment: I've tried your approach and it work wrong for existing record because it always selected value from 'selected: <value>'

Comment: I use next: `selected: f.object.field || default_value`

Comment: you save my life

Comment: @kunashir `selected: f.object.field || default_value` can lead to unintended `nil` results.  I would recommend using presence to ensure the default value is called:
`selected: f.object.field.presence || default_value`